# APPSI Needscompiledextension

Tags: cplex, pyomo, docplex

I've been running an iterative optimization problem using pyomo, and was pointed to using their appsi solvers to reduce read/write time between iterations.
When I attempt to run the solver, I receive the following error message:

Solver <class 'pyomo.contrib.appsi.solvers.cplex.Cplex'> is not available (NeedsCompiledExtension).

I'm not sure what needs to be done to remove this error, as I'm pretty new to this space.

Thanks!